# Error in inserting values to db, webservice

Tags: php, web-services, xampp

So im trying to insert value into my database but i get an error and i dont know the solution.

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJufU.png)

This is my error log:

> PDOException\r\nCode: 42000\r\nMessage: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
> or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
> the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
> right syntax to use near 'desc, lat, lng, titulo, imagem) VALUES ('1',
> 'asdasd', '2.5', '4.5', 'arwawr'...' at line 1\r\nFile:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myslim\api\db\NotORM\Result.php\r\nLine:
> 161\r\nTrace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myslim\api\db\NotORM\Result.php(161):
> PDOStatement->execute(Array)\n#1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myslim\api\db\NotORM\Result.php(237):
> NotORM_Result->query('INSERT INTO rep...', Array)\n#2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myslim\api\db\NotORM\Result.php(252):
> NotORM_Result->insert_multi(Array)\n#3
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myslim\api\teste.php(93):
> NotORM_Result->insert(Array)\n#4 [internal function]:
> Closure->{closure}(Object(Slim\Http\Request),
> Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)\n#5
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myslim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponse.php(40):
> call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Slim\Http\Request),
> Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)\n#6
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myslim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Route.php(281):
> Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponse->__invoke(Object(Closure),
> Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)\n#7
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myslim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(117):
> Slim\Route->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request),
> Object(Slim\Http\Response))\n#8
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myslim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Route.php(268):
> Slim\Route->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request),
> Object(Slim\Http\Response))\n#9
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myslim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(503):
> Slim\Route->run(Object(Slim\Http\Request),
> Object(Slim\Http\Response))\n#10
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myslim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(117):
> Slim\App->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request),
> Object(Slim\Http\Response))\n#11
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myslim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(392):
> Slim\App->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request),
> Object(Slim\Http\Response))\n#12
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myslim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(297):
> Slim\App->process(Object(Slim\Http\Request),
> Object(Slim\Http\Response))\n#13
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myslim\index.php(10): Slim\App->run()\n#14
> {main}\r\nView in rendered output by enabling the
> "displayErrorDetails" setting.\r\n

```
 $app->post('/api/addrepp', function ($request) {
                require_once ('db/dbconnect.php');
              
              $idutilizador = $request->getParsedBody()['idutilizador'];
            $desc = $request->getParsedBody()['desc'];
            $lat = $request->getParsedBody()['lat'];
            $lng = $request->getParsedBody()['lng'];
            $titulo = $request->getParsedBody()['titulo'];
            $imagem = $request->getParsedBody()['imagem'];
                      
                $report = array(
                  "idutilizador" => $idutilizador,
                  "desc" => $desc,
                  "lat" => $lat,
                  "lng" => $lng,
                  "titulo" => $titulo,
                  "imagem" => $imagem,
                );
              
                $reports = $db->reportes();
                $result = $reports->insert($report);
              
                if($result == false) {
                  echo json_encode([ 'status' => false, 'message' => "Ocorreu um erro ao inserir report"], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
                }else{
                  echo json_encode([ 'status' => true, 'message' => "Report adicionado com sucesso"], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
                }
              
              });
```

Comment: `desc` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html), though I'd honestly be pretty surprised if PDO doesn't enclose table/column/etc. tokens in backticks.  Does the error persist if you re-name the column?

Comment: Thank you, it worked, never would get there alone.